# Update List[B] in TrieMap[A, List[B]] concurrently to build up a queue

Tags: java, scala, concurrency

If I have something like

```
val x: TrieMap[String, List[Int]] = TrieMap()
```

and I update it (in a concurrent context) with:

```
def updateWith(value: Int) = {
  x.put("key", value :: x.getOrElse("key", Nil))
}
```

I'm trying to build up a queue of `Int` values in the map but I'm aware this is horribly non-atomic and nasty.

How can I update the list (effectively creating a queue, that I will drain later) in a thread safe way?

Comment: An aside: Are you aware of [an immutable Queue with amortized O(1) enqueue-dequeue operations](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/immutable/Queue.html)?

Comment: Yep, thanks. I'm more interested in how to access mulitple queues concurrently whilst held in a map. Perhaps that's fine if the map's value (a queue) is always the same instance?